# GeoJSON format (Geography) for posting in Postman tin PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson, node-js

I am trying to do an update posting on Postman for the first using PostGIS / Geography file type and I don't know where I am going wrong.

I have included the model below of the table in pgamdin 4 / PostgreSQL that I need the posting to go to as well as the json format. I know about GeoJSONs but I'm not sure if these are just JSONs with coordinates. I am trying to pull object description details along with the co-ordinates so i can display them on the marker.

Am I going about this the right way?

My JSON posting that isn't working is below:

```
{
    "diveSchoolName": "Forever Dive",
    "diveSchoolLocation": "Madagascar",
    "diveSchoolRegionID": 5,
    "diveCertificatesOfferedID": 1,
    "diveSpotsOfferedID": 1,
    "diveSchoolGeo": {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geography": {
            "type": "Geography",
            "coordinates": [-18.7669, 46.8691]
        }    
    }
    }
```

model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {

    const approvedDivingSchool = sequelize.define("approvedDivingSchools", {

        diveSchoolID: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        diveSchoolName: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT
        },
        diveSchoolLocation: {
            type: Sequelize.TEXT
        },
        diveSchoolRegionID: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        diveCoursesOffered: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        diveSpotsOfferedID: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        diveSchoolGeo: {
            type: Sequelize.GEOGRAPHY
        }},
        {
            timestamps: false
        })

    return approvedDivingSchool;
};
```

If I am posting a GeoJSON would it be inserted into one field in my PostgreSQL table or if I am pulling data from a table with coordinates is it automatically a GeoJSON? I'd prefer not to be duplicating work if information is already included in the GeoJSON.